How can I properly mock `cmp` method from `filecmp` in a test?
I am working on a Python function that synchronizes files to a cache directory. The goal is to check if a cached file exists and is up-to-date, and if not, replace it with a new version from the original file. Here's the code for the function:
   def sync_to_cache(self, original_file_path: Path, cache_dir: Path) -> None:
      try:
        cached_file_path = cache_dir.joinpath(original_file_path.name)

        if cached_file_path.exists() and cached_file_path.is_file() and cmp(original_file_path,   cached_file_path):
          # cached file already up to dat
          return

        # copy origiinal file to cache
        with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir=cache_dir, prefix="tmp", suffix=".rs") as   temp_file:
          temp_file_path = Path(temp_file.name)
          shutil.copy2(original_file_path, temp_file_path)
          temp_file.flush()
          temp_file.close()

          # replace old cached file
          temp_file_path.replace(cached_file_path)  # successful sync!
      except PermissionError as e:
        logger.exception(f"Permission error while syncing {original_file_path} to cache: {e}")  # noqa: TRY401
      except FileNotFoundError as e:
        logger.exception(f"File not found during synchronization: {e}")  # noqa: TRY401
      except IOError as e:
        logger.exception(f"I/O error during synchronization: {e}")  # noqa: TRY401
      except Exception as e:
         logger.exception(f"Unexpected error while caching {original_file_path}: {e}")  # noqa:TRY401

I wrote the following test for it:
    @mock.patch("tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile", autospec=True)
    @mock.patch("shutil.copy2", autospec=True)
    @mock.patch("pathlib.Path.exists", autospec=True)
    @mock.patch("pathlib.Path.is_file", autospec=True)
    @mock.patch("filecmp.cmp", autospec=True)
    def test_file_syncing(
      self, mock_eq: mock.MagicMock, mock_is_file: mock.MagicMock, mock_exists: mock.MagicMock, shutil_mock: mock.MagicMock, mock_temp_file: mock.MagicMock
  ) -> None:
      # mocks
      mock_exists.return_value = True
      mock_is_file.return_value = True
      mock_eq.return_value = False

      # mock for NamedTemporaryFile
      temp_file = mock.MagicMock()
      temp_file.name = "temp_file_path.rs"
      mock_temp_file.return_value.__enter__.return_value = temp_file

      # mock objects for Path
      original_file_path = mock.MagicMock(spec=Path)
      cache_dir = mock.MagicMock(spec=Path)
      cached_file_path = mock.MagicMock(spec=Path)
      cache_dir.joinpath.return_value = cached_file_path

      # instance of the class containing the function
      obj = Finder()
      obj.sync_to_cache(original_file_path, cache_dir)

      # since the file needs updating, copy and replace should happen
      shutil_mock.assert_called_once_with(original_file_path, temp_file.name)
      temp_file.replace.assert_called_once_with(cached_file_path)

  
I wrote a unit test using unittest.mock to mock out the various components of the file system. Here’s the test:

` File "C:\Users\pc\.rye\py\cpython@3.12.3\Lib\filecmp.py", line 53, in cmp
    s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'MagicMock/mock/1437965668176'
`
It seems that the `cmp` function is attempting to access an actual file on the system, even though I have explicitly mocked it to return False.

How can I correctly mock the `cmp` function so that it does not try to access the file system? I have tried using the `==` operator to avoid calling `cmp`, but that leads to errors stating that the files were not found.


I would refactor this quite a bit. The code to unit-test should operate on file-like objects as much as possible so that you don't need to mock anything. sync_to_cache is an instance method, but it never once uses self. You should also minimize how much code actually gets executed in a single try block, because it's not obvious what code might raise what exception, and thus hard to tell if you are handling exceptions properly.

what do you mean when you say, "sync_to_cache is an instance method, but it never once uses self"? I have all that code in the try block because because am handling every possible error or exception.
I will try refactoring and see if I get any change.
Thanks

sync_to_cache takes self as an argument, but never uses it. It might as well be a static method (which doesn't receive an implicit argument) or a regular function.

As for the try block, cached_file_path = cache_dir.joinpath(original_file_path.name) (for example) cannot raise an IOError (as it does no I/O, only string manipulation), so there's no sense trying to catch an IOError while executing it. Also, you aren't "handling" any error, only logging them. Nothing about the return value tells you what, if anything, was successfully done.

I understand now. Thank you. I tried the suggested improvements but nothing changed. I think some cmp internals are interfering with the mock. I did some research and in the future I plan to use hypothesis for units tests of functionality to test e2e by automating with docker.
I decided to use manual tests and solved the problem for now.
